# Overlay figure (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, overlay

I have a file of the Earth's landmass, where sea pixels are values of 0 and land pixels are values of 1. Sea pixels are blue and land pixels are green by defining

```
imagesc(landmass)
colormap('winter')
```

Now I want to plot the spread of a disease (matrix with the same size as landmass) on top of this map with a for loop which dynamically updates this spread. However, I do not know how do it correctly. When there is no disease in a certain pixel, it should just display the landmass file. When there is a disease on the pixel, it has to be overwritten by the disease matrix.

```
image(disease);
map = 'jet';
colormap(map);
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work (so this is inside the loop which updates the disease matrix):

```
for t=1:365
   disease=disease+t;
   figure(1);      
   imagesc(landmass)
   colormap('winter')
   hold on;
   if disease>0
      image(disease);
      map = 'jet';
      colormap(map);
   end
  title(sprintf('Day %i',t));                                 
  drawnow;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take your original matrix, `landmass` and update it at the index where you want to overlay the data instead of only updating the disease array. You could change your code to do something like the following

```
landmass(x,y,:)=diseasepixel;
imagesc(landmass);
```

Where diseasepixel would be the value of the color you want at that point.

Comment: Hmm, I don't reallt understand this. Can you provide more information? Thanks

Comment: To be clearer, if you are trying to place a diseased pixel on top of the landmass picture, just change the value of the landmass matrix at that point and update the image.